# What is the behavior of a c# Static Variable in a non-static class instance?

Tags: c#, class, static

What happens when I declare a static variable in a class and then instantiate the class many times?

Will the static variable be shared across all instances? Or will multiple static variables are created for each class instance?

Comment: I see no reason to downvote, especially without supporting comments

Comment: no worries... Me = idiot

Comment: @DavidL: You can find the answer on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/79b3xss3(v=vs.100).aspx), isn't the definition of `static` that it's shared across all instances? _"Only one copy of a static member exists, regardless of how many instances of the class are created"_ Imho this is just a rtfm question: [`static`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx(v=vs.110).aspx): _"While an instance of a class contains a separate copy of all instance fields of the class, there is only one copy of each static field."_

Comment: @TimSchmelter While that may be obvious to you or I, it may not have been to him.  And if so, all I really want to see is constructive criticism associated with comments.  We're all here to learn and grow, not demean.

Comment: @DavidL: Have a look at the downvote-link's tooltip. _"This question does not show any research effort"_ http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97880/is-lack-of-other-research-a-reason-to-downvote

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `static` field in C# is shared across all instances of a type.  No matter how many times you instantiate the type there will only be one instance of the static field per `AppDomain` (typically one `AppDomain` per process).

The one exception to this is for generic types.  When you have a static field in a generic type there will be one instance of the static field per generic instantiation.

```
class Container<T> {
  internal static T Field;
}
```

Now `Container<int>` and `Container<string>` will have different instances of `Field`

Comment: Thanks for adding the piece on generics.  Very useful info!